# Giving unique ID's to cloned elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I have draggable items that can be cloned. I wanted each clone to be unique so each of them can be inserted into our database (with coordinates, which will be done later on).

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    cntb1 = 0;
    cntb2 = 0;
    cntb3 = 0;
 $(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: '#b1, #b2, #b3',        
        drop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.draggable.attr('id')=='b1'){
                cntb1++;    //counts clones
                $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());               
                $(".droppable .drag").addClass("component");
                $(".component").removeClass("drag");
                $(".component").resizable({aspectRatio: 'true' }).parent().draggable({ //parent() -> both draggable & resizable work
                        containment: '.droppable', //cursor: 'move', grid: [3,3]                        
                }).attr('id', 'b1c'+cntb1); //change id
                $("#status1").append('b1c'+cntb1);
            }
        else if(ui.draggable.attr('id')=='b2'){
                cntb2++;    //counts clones
                $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());               
                $(".droppable .drag").addClass("component");
                $(".component").removeClass("drag");
                $(".component").resizable({aspectRatio: 'true' }).parent().draggable({ //parent() -> both draggable & resizable work
                        containment: '.droppable', //cursor: 'move', grid: [3,3]                        
                }).attr('id', 'b2c'+cntb2); //change id
                $("#status2").append('b2c'+cntb2);
            }
        else if(ui.draggable.attr('id')=='b3'){
                cntb3++;    //counts clones
                $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());               
                $(".droppable .drag").addClass("component");
                $(".component").removeClass("drag");
                $(".component").resizable({aspectRatio: 'true' }).parent().draggable({ //parent() -> both draggable & resizable work
                        containment: '.droppable', //cursor: 'move', grid: [3,3]                        
                }).attr('id', 'b3c'+cntb3); //change id
                $("#status3").append('b3c'+cntb3);
            }

    }
}); 

$(".drag").draggable({ 
            helper:'clone', 
            appendTo: 'body', //para maka drag padung gawas sa accordion
            cursor: 'move' 
            });
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({                   
            autoHeight: false,                  
            collapsible: true,
            active: false
});
});
```

But the problem is that whenever i create a new clone the ID of the old clone gets replaced with the ID of the new one. I tested it by styling ID's like this:

```
        #b1c3{ background:#00FF00; }
        #b1c2{ background:#CCFF00; }
```

My HTML is like this btw:

```
    <div id="accordion">
 <h3><a href="#">Buttons</a></h3>   
     <div class="div-table">         
        <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-col"><img src="button_final/button_1.gif" id="b1" class="drag"/></div>
        <div class="div-table-col"><img src="button_final/button_2.gif" id="b2" class="drag"/></div>
        <div class="div-table-col"><img src="button_final/button_3.gif" id="b3" class="drag"/></div>
        </div>
          </div>
</div>
<div id="frame" style="border:dotted; height:500px; width:60%; float:left" class="droppable">
<h3 id="status1" style="height:30%;"></h3>
<h3 id="status2" style="height:30%;"></h3>
<h3 id="status3" style="height:30%;"></h3></div>
```

ps. I assembled everything with the help of people here. I owe you my life!

Comment: Your abusing the concept of the id, use css properly

Comment: @Raynos how do i do that sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for sure,the change is that u have to assign an id at the time of appending it to droppable,previously u were assigning id to all the elements with component class which is wrong in your case.
so the only change will be :

```
 $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().attr("id",'b1c'+cntb1));
```

Comment: thank you sir. it helped. and i just used the id to apply stuff. :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this would be to not use ids in the cloned elements, to only use class names.  You can use an id on the one parent object if you need to, but keeping ids out of the things that are actually cloned will keep you from having to fix the ids in the cloned elements.

We could help further with fixing the id if you showed us the actual HTML that you are cloning so we know what id values need to be fixed.

Comment: I avoid IDs like the plague. Anything you may ever think of reusing should not have an ID

Comment: (sorry but i'm a bit slow at understanding things) that is my entire code. O_O so there isn't any way to add unique ids to clones when not made with different classes?

Comment: This is your entire HTML?  I don't see anything with a class of `"component"` in the HTML you've provided and I don't know what HTML it is that you're cloning and need to fix the IDs in.  If I know the exact HTML that you're cloning and where the IDs are, it is possible to fix them, but without knowing that, there is no automatic way to do it.

Comment: @jfriend00 maybe I misunderstood adding classes. I thought that if I add a class that does not exist it would be created. Anyway, thank you for trying to help. Thought of a solution and I got it to work. can't post an answer to my own question yet though. 6 hours before I can do that.

Comment: @chaypotato - Also, if you're going to generate dynamic IDs to have them be non-conflicting, then they aren't really known to your javascript code so you probably don't even need an id in the first place.

Comment: @chaypotato - A class is just a tag on an element that can be used to help find or style that element.  You can have more than one class on an element.  It has nothing to do with creating elements.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh, I see.. I just learned jquery and javascript a couple of weeks ago and have so much more to learn. As of now I look for the easiest way out of a problem. Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting everything with the class `$(".component")` and not just the newly added/cloned element.

You need to limit it to just that one.

One thing you can do is instead of appending the elemtn and finding it, you can store a reference to it

```
//$(this).append($(ui.helper).clone()); 
var newClone = $(ui.helper).clone();
$(this).append(newClone); 
//than you can manipulate newClone to add/remove classes. Use find(), etc
```

Comment: you mean replacing this
$(".droppable .drag").addClass("component");
                $(".component").removeClass("drag");
to this                $(".droppable .drag").addClass("component");
                $("#myid").removeClass("drag");
? i wanted them to have the same class but different ids

Comment: But when you have more than one element on the page with .component, you are selecting more than one element.

Comment: ahk im so weak at this. haha. but wont that have the same effect since its always "newClone" that's the clone? i'm so confused. so sorry i'm such a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem ,solution is to assign the id to component before making it resizable.

```
  $(".component").removeClass("drag").attr('id', 'b1c'+cntb1);
                    $(".component").resizable({aspectRatio: 'true' }).parent().draggable({ //parent() -> both draggable & resizable work
                            containment: '.droppable', //cursor: 'move', grid: [3,3]                        
                    });
```

Comment: it still overwrites the old id with the new one. :(

Comment: Added a new answer so kindly check it :-)

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone for helping! I'm confused as to what I was trying to do in the first place. But anyway if someone else wanted to do this, this might help:

`$(".droppable .drag").addClass("component").attr('id', 'b1c'+cntb1); /*basin if ako e change ang id diri */`

`$("#b1c"+cntb1).removeClass("drag"); //nya ang id name ako e call instead na ang class`

`$("#b1c"+cntb1).resizable({aspectRatio: 'true' }).parent().draggable({ containment: '.droppable' });`

This worked for me. Thank you @Mehul Hingu for the idea. :)